# Split single big csv file into multiple csv files on the basis of size and preserve file header of source file through UNIX

Tags: csv, unix

What we have got :  A single file csv file with field names as header.

What we need :

1. On the basis of size of the file we need to split it into multiple smaller csv files with exptension _00*.

Condtion : If file_size < 5 GB then no action.
           If File_size > 5 GB then Split it into Multiple file with any  dimension that ranges between ( 1 GB to < 5 GB ) . 
Here we need to take care that while splitting the file by size we don't split a single record.

2. We need to preserve the header record of source file and replicate it into each new file.
3. Along with each small file a blank file with same name but with extension (.ok) needs to be created . It is just for notification that the file got created.
4. In the end delete the source file. Only keep new files. and create 1 final file with same name as source file but with extension .ok

Ex :  Source file : file_name_20160316.csv  size : 8.8 Gb

Output :

file_name_20160316_001.csv ( size : 4 GB) 
file_name_20160316_001.ok
file_name_20160316_002.csv ( size : 4.8 GB) 
file_name_20160316_002.ok
file_name_20160316.ok

Please help us writing Unix code for the same.

Comment: This isn't a question but a specification, and as it currently stands is more appropriate to post on one of the many freelance programming websites.  As the saying goes, SO is not a code-writing service.  There are many questions on SO about splitting csvs with tools from awk to Python: if you're using one and having a problem with it, then you should edit your question to be more specific about your difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p

BEGIN
{
    $dim = 5e9;
    $header = <>;           # We need to preserve the header record
    exit if -s ARGV < $dim; # If file_size < 5 GB then no action.
    $headsize = $told = tell;
                            # ranges between ( 1 GB to < 5 GB )
    $dim = ($dim+(-s _)/int(1+(-s _)/$dim))/2 if (-s _)%$dim <= 1e9;
    ($base = $ARGV) =~ s/.csv/_/;
    $extent = "000"
}

if (tell > $lim)            # need new file?
{
    $lim = $told+$dim-$headsize;
    open OK, ">$base$extent.ok" and close OK if $output;
    $output = $base.++$extent.'.csv';
    open STDOUT, ">$output" or die "$output: $!\n";
    print $header           # replicate into each new file.
}

$told = tell;

END
{
    open OK, ">$base$extent.ok" and close OK if $output;
    chop $base;
    unlink $ARGV and open OK, ">$base.ok" and close OK
}
```